# Set background color: always black despite horizon color?

Tags: color

[The documentation here](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/world/world_panel.html) says

[image]

So I followed, setting mine as follows

[image]

However, the rendered background is still black instead of white, as below.

What might've gone wrong here? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: enable the box that reads **Blend Sky**

Comment: @cegaton Thanks for the prompt help! I did (http://imgur.com/a/hdlKE), but still black background unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried changing all three colors to white?

Comment: @CyberBurst Changing ambient color to white makes the object white-ish, and meanwhile the background is still black...

Comment: @MrZak Sorry for being unclear. I've updated the screenshot so that you can see the background isn't really white. What I care most is the final rendering generated by clicking the "Animation" button. In that rendering, the background is pure black.

Comment: Do you mean that if you render using F12 (not animation) it renders with white color ? And is that rendered model and the background on the screenshot (because it looks like it is in Solid shading mode) ?

Comment: Thanks! This is the rendering in Blender after clicking the "Render" button: http://imgur.com/a/UQgVm, and this is the `.png` image (viewed outside of Blender) I got after clicking the "Animation" button:  http://imgur.com/a/XDIfE. My apologies for causing the confusion. Thanks again.

Comment: So you are using alpha in *Shading* rollout in BI (you might want to edit question with that). In that case you won't see the background in BI (it's considered as transparent). As to 3rd party viewer - can it preview alpha channel ? In anyway that .png (despite of quite bad interpreting alphas by .png) is transparent in black areas. The animated output should be rendered into image sequence (preferably not png) and overlayed with Alpha Over, not rendered into video directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to view the background in the viewport, in the Properties Tool Shelf (Shown by pressing the "N" key) and under the "Display" tab, check "World Background"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Z</kbd>

This switches to *Rendered Viewport shading* and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is the hotkey that toggles it on and off.

If this does not work, try uploading the .blend file?

Answer (score -1):

In shading section of the *render* tab in the Properties panel, change the Alpha from Transparent to Sky (little camera icon).
I faced the same problem in Blender render.

Comment: Please avoid using multiple exclamation marks and punctuation in your answer. This makes your answer look messy and not like a serious answer. Also make sure your grammar is good enough for non-native English speakers to understand, and screenshots added to your answer can really help others out in finding what you're talking about. Click the "edit" button below your answer to make the proper changes.

Answer (score -1):

Change to the cycles render,  I'm using blender 2.79b. Only changing the render works for me.